# How to insert a function inside a .tick() handler on the fly in aframe?

Tags: aframe

I want to remove a piece of code inside a .tick handler in AFRAME using js.

This is what I have:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
 schema: {},
 init: function () {},
 update: function () {},
 tick: function() {
        myObject.position.y += 0.009;//this is what I want to remove on the fly
 },
remove: function () {},
pause: function () {},
play: function () {}
});
```

I expect to trigger the add or removal of that piece of code on the fly using js.

Answer (score 2):

Sorround your logic with an if statement that checks for the appropriate conditions:

```
tick: function() {
  if (conditions) {
     myObject.position.y += 0.009;
  }
}
```

You can set those conditions anywhere in your code: component local or global variable, component property...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I used the conditional like this:

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
 schema: {},
 init: function () {
  condition = false;
    },
 update: function () {},
 tick: function() {
    if (condition == true) {
    myObject.position.y += 0.009;//this is what I want to remove on the fly
      }
 },
remove: function () {},
pause: function () {},
play: function () {}
});
```

Now I can trigger the state with:

```
    condition = false;
```

Comment: Good job! Another idea is adding the condition as part of the [schema](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-properties-with-the-schema) to avoid the global variable: `schema: {enabled: { default: false }}` and you can do `el.setAttribute(‘foo’, {enabled: false})`

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the point of schema and updates, but you are really really close with your logic.

I would add the condition into the schema so that you can use it anywhere within your component as well as use AFrame sugar to update it using setAttribute.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  schema: {
    condition: {type: boolean, default:false}
  },
  init: function () {
    //possible once off initialization logic
  },
  update: function () {},
  tick: function() {
    if (this.data.codition) {
      myObject.position.y += 0.009;//this is what I want to remove on the fly
    }
  },
  remove: function () {},
  pause: function () {},
  play: function () {}
});
```

Then on the fly you simply do

yourElementWithFooComponent.setAttribute("condition":"true"/"false");